# How do I embed a quicktime movie into an iphone web app using dashcode?

Tags: javascript, iphone, video, quicktime, dashcode

I have a functional webapp that I have created through dashcode, but I want to add a video by clicking a button. Any idea on how to code a handler to do that or any sample code? thanks

here is what I have but it wont do anything in the simulator

```
function myClickHandlerVideo(event)
{
    var vidElem=document.createElement("video");
    vidElem.setAttribute("src", "OrangeReel_v001.mov");
    vidElem.play();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very simple:

```
function myClickHandlerReel(event) 
{
    var websiteURL = "myMovie.m4v";
    location = websiteURL
}
```